# Process.Start(file) issue

Tags: vb.net

```
Private Sub FlatButton5_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles FlatButton5.Click
    If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) & "\LauncherArma\directory.a3") Then
        file = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) & "\LauncherArma\directory.a3") & "\arma3.exe"
        Process.Start(file)
    Else
        MsgBox("Choose ARMA III Folder before!", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Errore")
    End If

End Sub
```

As you can see in this script, once the arma3 folder is selected, if the user click over "Start Arma3" the game opens. What I want to do is to create a URL where, by clicking on Start Arma3, the game starts directly to the server. What I did, on website is a kinda of like like: `steam://run/107410//-mod=@Mod%20-connect=IP ADDR%20-port=port n`

What I need to extract from the like above is the -Mod and the rest. 
How can I Make it working on VB.NET?

Regards

Comment: Seems like the server would have to be able to take commands - do you know this process?

Comment: @OneFineDay, on browser, using that link, it works. Click here for more info https://community.bistudio.com/wiki/Arma_3_Dedicated_Server#Headless_Client

Comment: Looks like you would start the exe for streaming commands and pass the command to that process - look into [ProcessStartInfo](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&sqi=2&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fsystem.diagnostics.processstartinfo%2528v%3Dvs.110%2529.aspx&ei=__CeVPTcEtWjyASd_ICYAw&usg=AFQjCNGnI9JImxht2WMerqHZQPJCINLWoQ&sig2=u8OdWGVUaKG4m7NC6N6hJw&bvm=bv.82001339,d.aWw)

Comment: @OneFineDay, still not clear. In that case, I've to work after Process.Start(file). How do I move to create an argument without changing the folder as set below?

Comment: If there is a command line utility for sending command to the server - that is the process you need to start with the arguments on the ProcessStartInfo object.

Comment: In my case, if I need to add this string, when the game is starting, where do I have to add it?

Can you write the string plz?

Ty

Comment: I'm not familiar with this game or the commands, read the site info, do some trial and error... Sorry I cannot help further.

Comment: I got you, but would be nice if you post here how you will structure the parameter for launching the mod etc. ..Don't need to know the game

Comment: Why not just use the same URI from the website? If the system has the Steam URI handler installed, `Process.Start("steam://...)` should give you the same results as clicking the link on the website.